# Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545

Tags: javascript, npm, web3js

**Screenshot of the issues:**
[image]
   Web3.min.js path in my system directory!

[image]
   Web3.min.js is loaded from folder in my browser

[image]
   Copy of the web3.min.js in the same folder where index.html file is present.

[image]
   Code added

[image]

info of the node!
[image]
    **I am facing following two issues:**

1. Failed to load resource: web3.min.js:1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
2. ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545.

   **My Index.html file is**

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       <title>Document</title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
   ```

   ```
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container">

           <h1>Coursetro Instructor</h1>

           <h2 id="instructor"></h2>

           <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Name</label>
           <input id="name" type="text">

           <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Age</label>
           <input id="age" type="text">

           <button id="button">Update Instructor</button>


       </div>

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

       <script>
         if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
               web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
           } else {
               // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
               web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
           }
           web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
           var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([
       {
           "constant": false,
           "inputs": [
               {
                   "name": "_fName",
                   "type": "string"
               },
               {
                   "name": "_age",
                   "type": "uint256"
               }
           ],
           "name": "setInstructor",
           "outputs": [],
           "payable": false,
           "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
           "type": "function"
       },
       {
           "constant": true,
           "inputs": [],
           "name": "getInstructor",
           "outputs": [
               {
                   "name": "",
                   "type": "string"
               },
               {
                   "name": "",
                   "type": "uint256"
               }
           ],
           "payable": false,
           "stateMutability": "view",
           "type": "function"
       }
   ]);       
   var Coursetro=CoursetroContract.at('0x95712aa4ff464e56f76af55da6239a368c459ed4');
       console.log(Coursetro);

       </script>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. Are you trying to connect to a local provider or through MetaMask? If you're using a local provider, can you post info on when you start the node?

Comment: yes i am trying to connect to a local provider http://localhost:8545. not using metamask and here it is the screenshot of the info of node.(attached)

Answer (score 0):

**If you are connecting to a local node:**

You have included jquery cdn, similarly include a web3 from the link [web3_cdn](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist).
You can download one file from the link and connect the file in your webapp by

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>
```

And make sure when you run the app your metamask is disabled. Metamask injects a web3 object right into your application.

For reference check the other answers [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19483/how-can-the-web3-library-be-imported-in-a-web-application)

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your help but i am not getting it why my script is not able to find the web3.min.js although it is download in package and exist in my system and i have given its correct path to my script as you can see in my index.html file           <script src="C:/Users/iluqman.TRGWORLD/coursetro-eth/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script> you can see my attached screenshot

Comment: try the following 
1. copy the `web3.min.js`  in the same folder as index.html
2. disable metamask
Check in the browser source if the web3.min.js is loaded from the folder

Comment: i have tried your suggested solution while metamask is disable. and i have checked Web3.min.js is loaded from the folder in the browser source. but nothing goes right for me. :( you can see the screenshot attached above.

Comment: which ethereum client you are using? and I don't see this line in your code.
<script type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry i am quite new on it but i think i'm using Ethereum TestRpc.and you can see screenshot for the code line added in my script.

Comment: Issue was resolved later by running following commands on command prompt ">cd Foldername" after accessing folder using command prompt and then run ">npm install web3"

Answer (score -3):

i have this problem and i solve it .

the solution :

you must create index.html and main.css in folder project, not in node_modules folder.

Comment: in the screen shorts and code you can see her index.html and the main.css

Comment: The files you have mentioned are not inside node_modules.