# Connect a smart contract to HTML code via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to follow this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcTPjpPvas8&ab_channel=DesignCourse) to build a webpage that can interact with a smart contract.
It uses this code in remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Coursetro {
    
   string fName;
   uint age;
   
   function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
   }
   
   function getInstructor() public constant returns (string, uint) {
       return (fName, age);
   }
    
}
```

And this code which I have set up in visual studio code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <!-- <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Coursetro Instructor</h1>

        <h2 id="instructor"></h2>

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Age</label>
        <input id="age" type="text">

        <button id="button">Update Instructor</button>


    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }

        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

        var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([
            {
                "constant": false,
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "_fName",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "_age",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "setInstructor",
                "outputs": [],
                "payable": false,
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "constant": true,
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getInstructor",
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "payable": false,
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            }
        ]);

        var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x0CF6A859635A0729d14b524d05619c7162A102bd');
        console.log(Coursetro);

        Coursetro.getInstructor(function(error, result){
            if(!error)
                {
                    $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)');
                    console.log(result);
                }
            else
                console.error(error);
        });

        $("#button").click(function() {
            Coursetro.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val());
        });



    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I try to pull it up on the local host I've set it up on. localhost:8545, it gives me a 400 Bad Request with this in the console:
[image]

So I tried using an http-server command which successfully set up a site I can visit, but I am receiving these errors in the console:
[image]

Just wondering if anyone has had this issues before and knows how to fix them? Or if there is something I've missed and that's why I'm getting the errors.

Comment: is your ethereumjs local blockchain/node running at the specified address/port? If so, did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? Seems its not finding your running node

Comment: I used npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc in the command prompt and then when I called testrpc it said listening on localhost:8545. I have it working on 172.25.208.1:8081/test.html and thats where the second console errors screenshot comes from, not sure if that makes a difference or if I have even answered your question at all. Let me know if I need to clarify more please.

Comment: Try these solutions and see if any work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410125/couldnt-connect-to-node-http-localhost8545